# How do you create security api application in Laravel5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have something uncertainty when I use laravel-5 to create api application.

Usually , when I got some user info from server, I should `post uid(user_id)` to server, but looks like unsafe.Anyone can catch it(Network packets) and do anything.

So , are you use this way or use authentication in laravel, as far as I know, authentication in laravel will auto-Expired, if you have best way, please tell me .

Answer (score 0):

For a REST API I prefer Basic Auth, in L5 this is implemented in the middleware.
I recomend you [this excelent tutorial](http://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-rest-api-basic-authentication/):

Another way is with the help of [JSON Web Token](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)

This is a very decent [JWT package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for L4 and L5

But I prefer the first way, seems very easy and strightforward to me.

Comment: At this case , it use **Auth::onceBasic** . so means , iOS and Android should put username and password of base64 in http header every request ? It seems.... Uncomfortable

Comment: On the other hand you have [JWT](http://jwt.io/) and of course [OAuth2](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/taylorotwell/laravel-oauth2)